# Android - How to reload data after Volley request

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-volley, notifydatasetchanged

My question is simple. I have a simple fragment which is **not a list** but simply 5 TextViews. Once this fragment runs, it fires a volley request to an API endpoint where its response arrives after the onCreateView method has already finished. Normally, one would use **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** so that the new data could be shown even if it arrives after the normal fragment lifecycles have ended. The problem is that since my fragment is not a list, it does not have an adapter. How could I use notifyDataSetChanged() in the absence of an adapter? What solution should I be looking for to solve this problem? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh. right.. the request already has a listener.. was thinking of something different there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a field of

```
private TextView textView1;
```

And somewhere you have a `StringRequest` for Volley, then in the `onResponse` for the `Response.Listener`, just set the text of the TextView.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    textView1.setText(response);
}
```

If you have a seprate class that does your Volley requests, then you should add a parameter for `Response.Listener` to your method.

For example

```
MyServer.doLogin("http://myurl.com/login", "username:password", new Response<String>.Listener() {
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Do something here
    }
};
```

Where `MyServer.doLogin` could be something like this (note: this is an example, it may not compile)

```
public void doLogin(String url, String cred, Response<String>.Listener callback) {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
        url, 
        Request.GET, 
        callback,
        new Response.ErrorListener() { ... }
    );

    addToRequestQueue(request); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @cricket_007. I believe your answer is correct. The only problem is that I'm trying to keep a MVC approach and my request is located in a separate class. I normally try to follow best practices and I try to place only lifecycle methods on the fragment. With that in mind what object would I have to pass to the response so that I could update the data in the cleanest way possible? Could you point me in the right direction? Do you agree that would be best to have the volley request in a separate class? Let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I do that with my Volley stuff and I've adopted the pattern shown in my edits

Answer (score 0):

You may try to reset the data collection and use Invalidate()to refresh the view ,try to mix these operations in a method and call them when you need.